# What is Java runtime multilanguage for?

Tags: jvm, java

I'm dealing with a software vendor who says that,  application needs JVM multilanguage. But I read about java locale and java 6 support almost(if not ) all country locales. So what's the difference between jvm multilanguage and, just the jre installer on Oracle site?

Comment: I thought it was built in to the JRE/JVM, too.  I'd challenge the vendor and ask what they're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the old days, you could download a US-English version of the JRE and an Internationalized version.  For example: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase11-419415.html#7452-jre-1.1.8_15-oth-JPR

They discontinued the English-only JRE bundles with Java 1.5.  So the vendor's requirement is moot ... unless you are using a really old JVM.

Answer (score 0):

JVM Multi-language refers to support running code from other programming languages like Ruby/JRuby, Groovy, Scala, etc. Oracle JVM is one of them. Probably, the software you're dealing with need support to other programming languages for some reason.

Comment: I don't think this explanation matches the OP's situation.  Besides, any JVM that implements the JVM specification is capable of running code from those languages.  If a JVM doesn't, it is not a real JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the vendor what they mean - do they mean internationalized support (i.e. multiple human languages) - or do they mean that some components of the vendor software are written in a non-Java JVM computer language (e.g. Scala, Jython, Clojure, etc), and that you will also need the runtime support components for those non-Java languages.